# The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS

Tags: symfony

I try to run this command

```
> symfony new my_project_name
```

But it gave me this error.

> [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
> The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.

Comment: And what's your question about this? Is there anything unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to activate openssl in your php.ini.

To find your current php.ini file execute this command `php --ini`

Then add this line

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
...
extension=openssl  <---
```

Restart php services (`task manager > CGI / FastCGI > End task`) to be sure to apply modification.

Also, be sure that the php_openssl.dll is inside of your `php/installation/path/ext/` directory.

Example :
[image]

Comment: i couldnt find CGI / FastCGI in my task manager

Comment: If not found in the task manager, you may be use IIS, Wamp Server or any other webserver. Otherwise, if you're on linux https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-restart-php-service-command/